# Core Java Volume 1 chapter 6 6.4.7 static inner class

Tags: java, inner-classes

there.
I've been learning Java from Core Java Volume 1 9th Edition, I'm a bit confused about an example from the book (Listing 6.8)
Why is there a 'Pair' before method name (`minmax`) of the class 'ArrayAlg'?

```
public static Pair minmax(double[] values)
```

The source code is as below:

```
package staticInnerClass;

public class StaticInnerClassTest
{    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double[] d = new double[20];
        for (int i = 0; i < d.length; i++)
            d[i] = 100 * Math.random();
        ArrayAlg.Pair p = ArrayAlg.minmax(d);
        System.out.println("min = " + p.getFirst());
        System.out.println("max = " + p.getSecond());
    }    
}

class ArrayAlg
{
    /**
     * A pair of floating-point numbers
     */
    public static class Pair
    {
        private double first;
        private double second;

        /**
         * Constructs a pair from two floating-point numbers
         * @param f the first number
         * @param s the second number
         */
        public Pair(double f, double s)
        {
            first  = f;
            second = s;
        }

        /**
         * Returns the first number of the pair
         * @return the first number
         */
        public double getFirst()
        {
            return first;
        }

        /**
         * Returns the second number of the pair
         * @return the sceond number
         */
        public double getSecond()
        {
            return second;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Computes both the minimum and the maximum of an array
     * @param values an array of floating-point numbers
     * @return a pair whose first element is the minimum and whose second element is the maximum
     */
    public static Pair minmax(double[] values)
    {
        double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        double max = Double.MIN_VALUE;
        for (double v : values)
        {
            if (min > v)
                min = v;
            if (max < v)
                max = v;
        }
        return new Pair(min, max);
    }
}
```

Comment: That is the type of the return value of the method.

Comment: On a side note: A *static inner* class does not exist according to the JLS. It is called a *nested class*. An *inner* class is never static.

Answer (score 1):

The `Pair` in the declaration `public static Pair minmax(double[] values)` is the method's return type. The fact that `Pair` is an inner class is inconsequential, and if it were a top level class the declaration would look exactly the same (assuming you import the class, of course).

Answer (score 0):

`Pair` is a static inner class of `ArrayAlg` - there are various way to declare a variable of type `Pair` but the most common is as shown where the declaration takes the following form:

```
[outer class].[inner class] [variable name] = ...
```

It's as though the *outer class* is just another level in the full path, which would include the package, to the class (type) you're interested in.

While arguably the compiler could infer the variable type from the method return type, that's not how Java works and so you have to be explicit.